# How to print and print preview dialog box display?

Tags: c#

I created a web application for college.  I want to add print and print preview button to printing result of student.  Which classes are used for printing  a form?

My print and print preview button coding is below:

```
protected void btnprint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.gridcontrol != null)
    {
        GridPrintDocument gpd = new GridPrintDocument(this.gridcontrol, true);

        PrintDialog pritdlg = new PrintDialog();
        pritdlg.Document = gpd;

        if (pritdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            gpd.Print();
    }
    else
    {
        lblstatus.Text="An error occurred attempting to print the grid ";
    }
}

protected void btnprntprew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.gridcontrol != null)
    {
        //Uses the default printer.
        GridPrintDocument gpd = new GridPrintDocument(this.gridcontrol, true);
        PrintPreviewDialog pripredlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        pripredlg.Document = gpd;
        pripredlg.ShowDialog();
    }
    else
    {
        lblstatus.Text = "An error occurred attempting to preview the grid ";
    }
}
```

Comment: "PrintDialog" is WinForms in my opinion. How does this match with your statement that you are creating a _Web_ application?

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged your question as C#,so in C# printDialog and printPreviewDialog is the option to do the work which code will be..

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{

           e.Graphics.DrawString(richTextBox1.Text, richTextBox1.Font, Brushes.Black, 100, 20);  //richtextbox1 contains what you want to print

           e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Inch;          

}

private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

            //PrintDialog associate with PrintDocument;

            printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;

            if (printDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
            {
                printDocument1.Print();
            }
}

private void btnPrintPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       //Associate PrintPreviewDialog with PrintDocument.

        printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;  

        // Show PrintPreview Dialog

        printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
}
```

You can see this tutorial whether you want it in Asp.net

- [Creating-print-preview-page-dynamically-in-ASP-NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13795/Creating-print-preview-page-dynamically-in-ASP-NET)