# How to show print dialogue when i press control + P in windows form

Tags: c#

How to show print dialogue when i press control + P in windows form.
I have already a report1.rdlc and reportviewer1. in second form. How to print this report in Main(First form)?

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272845/how-to-print-and-print-preview-dialog-box-display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help:

1. add a PrintDialog to your form.

   2.Set its property to your Document.

.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
        if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.P)) {
            printDialog1.ShowDialog(this);
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Comment: Hi bro, How i set the property of PrintDialog as Report.rdlc

Answer (score 0):

first in load main
do this

```
Private Sub main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       Me.KeyPreview = True
    
    End Sub
```

then in event **KeyDown**  write the code

```
 If e.Control AndAlso e.KeyValue = Keys.P Then
    //somthing

     End If
```